# Export from vectornator for import to figma

Tags: figma

How can I edit projects created in the Vectornator in Figma?
It may be worth using intermediaries, such as Adobe Illustrator. Please, who has experience with Vectornator and Figma. How can I edit files in Figma that the designer sends me from Vectornator.

I tried to use svg, but it's very difficult to call it a correct transfer.